# send logs to grafana cloud with opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0 or loki-logback-appender for springboot3

Tags: java, spring-boot, grafana, logback, grafana-loki

- What I am trying to achieve

I would like to send SpringBoot3 application logs to grafana cloud (the paid product), directly, without intermediate, to loki backend.

- What did I try

I created a free trial account in grafana cloud.
I am having difficulties as it seems there are two jars available:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-logback-appender-1.0</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

vs

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.loki4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>loki-logback-appender</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which one is correct?
I would like to send the logs *directly* to loki backend using this construct:

```
<appender name="LOKI" class="???">
    <http>
        <url>???</url>
    </http>
```

Moreover, it seems from grafana cloud, that there are two endpoint.

```
https://logs-prod-006.grafana.net/loki/api/v1/push
```

vs

```
https://otlp-gateway-prod-us-east-0.grafana.net/otlp/v1/logs
```

Which one should I use in combination of which jar?

Comment: Loki != OpenTelemetry, so use everything what has loki in the name (you can use also OpenTelemetry, but then you need middle man for format conversion, e. g OTEL collector)